# System.web.http.dll deleted accidently

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly

I was trying to remove reference of System.web.http from my project but accidentally deleted it from .Net framework.

Any idea how can i recover it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You removed it from GAC?

Comment: Yes it has been removed from GAC too :(

Comment: Thank @AlexanderDayan and VMAtm for your comments. I have recovered dll from my system and pasted in reference assemblies folder as well as bin folder and now it is working :-)